# Best way to loop smtpmailer email php loop

Tags: php, email

I run a website where I would like to start sending out an email newsletter to the registered users that opted in.  Currently, there are about 700 users. I use a gmail account with smtpmailer to currently send all my notifications and it works well. However, when I ran my loop script to send out the personalized newsletter, the webpage with the loop eventually errors out after getting through maybe 100 users.

I didn't think this was really that heavy of a load.  Should I be following a better practice for this?

My code process is essentially as follows

1. Connect to server
2. set_time_limit(0);
3. While loop for all users who are subscribed
4. Build custom message
5. Send Email
6. End Loop

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not what your Gmail account is for.  Gmail intentionally puts blocks in place to prevent this or at least de-rail your attempts.

There are many free for small account SMTP providers out there with various restrictions.
http://www.SendGrid.com Send up to 400 emails a day (12,000 emails a month)
http://www.MailChimp.com Send 12,000 emails a month to a list of up to 2,000 subscribers

Those are two of the big ones but there are plenty of smaller outfits as well.

Comment: sendgrid looks like it would work really well. The reason I had concern though is that it didn't seem like Gmail was blocking the messages, it seems like the webpage I had that was going through the loop was timing out. If I used sendgrid's APIs and had their code in my loop, would that fix the problem?

Comment: Yes. SendGrid has both an API that you can call to send messages and also a plain SMTP server that you can connect to and send with.  Since you were using Gmail's SMTP just switching to SendGrid's should be easy for you.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail allows you to send only 50 mails per hour.

Comment: There are also additional limits such as a max number of emails in a to/cc/bcc list, emails per day, undeliverable addresses...etc. They will all cause problems.